# Is there a function in Java Streams where you can get the first char for every value, in a list of strings

Tags: java, java-stream

So at the moment I'm trying to learn about Java Streams for an upcoming test.
One of the questions says:

> Write functional code (using the streams API) that starts from a list
> of character strings, filters out all elements shorter than two
> characters, sorts the elements in alphabetical order and returns a
> list of the first character of each remaining character string.

I think I'm somewhat on the right path, but I can't get the "returns a list of the first character of each remaining character string." part to work.

I've gotten this far:

```
.streams.filter(p -> p > 1).sorted(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.toString()))
```

Even then I'm not sure if that's right but I'm trying to learn. So if anyone could push me to the right path I would be thankful.

Comment: Do you know how to get the first character of a string? If so, then just use a `map` operation that does that.

Comment: `....map(text -> text.charAt(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Your code and your requirement are in conflict.  You said *filters out all elements shorter than two characters,*.  But you're filtering out strings less that three characters by allowing those greater than two.  Which is it?

Comment: @WJS Sorry for the delayed answer, was away. But in short i wanted to filter out all elements shorter than two characters. The code is wrong i realised it later on. Thanks for pointing it out, i fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
List<Character> chars = 
    strings
        .stream()
        .filter(s1 -> s1.length() >= 2)
        .sorted()
        .map(s2 -> s2.charAt(0))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can use `map()` method to get first character for each string after applying filter and sorting. And String already implements Comparable you don't need to provide any sorting mechanism, it will be sorted in ascending order by default.

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question. I added a null check before the string lenght check, since theoretically, if you have null strings in the input list, you will get a NullPointerException.

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public static List<Character> fistCharAlphOrder(List<String> inputList) {
    return inputList
            .stream()
            .filter(s -> s != null && s.length() >= 2) // null check, considering strings of at least 2 chars
            .sorted() // sorting by default alphabetical order
            .map(s -> s.charAt(0)) // get the first char
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect the result into a List of Character
}
```